# How to test Get-ChildItem for no files as part of Invoke-Command?

Tags: powershell

I have the following script:

```
try {
Invoke-Command -Computer $Server -ScriptBlock { 
    param ($dir, $name)
    Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | 
        Where {$_.Name -Match "$name"} | 
            Remove-Item -confirm:$false -Recurse -Verbose 
} -ArgumentList $Directory, $DB

    Write-Host "`r`nsuccessfull! " -foregroundcolor yellow -backgroundcolor black
}
catch {
    write-host "`r`nFAILED!" -foregroundcolor red -backgroundcolor black
    Write-Host "$($error[0])`r`n" -foregroundcolor magenta -backgroundcolor black
}
```

if no files exist to delete...it currently still says "successful" as output...can i refine this to say 
`"there was no files to delete" else "successfully deleted x number of files"`?

also, the `recurse` on verbose is needed because otherwise i am forced to manually confirm even with confirm parameter. I think its because there are many sub items inside the target folder(s) i am looking to delete...

however, i get a TON of verbose messages for every single one of those items saying

> VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target
>   \name1\subitem
>
> VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on
>   target \name1\subitem1
>
> VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove
>   Directory" on target \name1\subitem2

can i make it so that it just prints verbose on a folder level instead for every single item?

> VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target \name1

Comment: [Why is -Verbose not working with Invoke-Command?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aabedd38-269e-42c0-bc83-e6bd6d6d1f33/why-is-verbose-not-working-with-invokecommand?forum=winserverpowershell)   ..... [Verbose not working with Invoke-Command...](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/verbose-not-working-with-invoke-command/)

Comment: So I accedently picked the wrong question. But that does not make it less valid. I consider your behaviour as f*cking rude and maximum unpolite. I arleady asked you  to at least place links to the other crossposts you make to let people willing to help you know that there might be already more information or even a solution. It's like you scream your question at the same time to three different rooms without even waiting for an answer in one of them...  :-/

Comment: But why you need to post the same question to three different forums AT THE SAME TIME? Just post it here and WAIT an appropriate amount of time for an answer!! That'll even easier for you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your file list to a variable that you can then inspect. Throwing everything through the pipeline is fine for quick-and-dirty, but not so much if you want to extract status information at various points.

```
$delfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Where {$_.Name -Match "$name"} 
If ($delfiles) {
    Write-Host "There are $($delfiles.count) to delete " 
    $delfiles | Remove-Item -confirm:$false -Recurse #put a try/catch here maybe
    Write-Host "`r`nsuccessful! "    
}
else {
    write-host "there were no files to delete"
}
```

Comment: but what about remotely doing this? invoking-command on computer

Comment: Dude, you literally put that inside your `-scriptblock { }`

Comment: is this by deafult gonna always point to C:\? because it just outputted no files are there to delete...i think im having same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508521/why-is-the-directory-being-redirected-to-c

Comment: what is inside your `$dir` variable, and is it being passed correctly to your scriptblock? What happens if you test with a specific path typed into the `Get-Childitem` rather than `$dir`? To be honest, this is basic troubleshooting, and I answered your original question - fi there was a problem with my *code*, I might help. But I'm not going to troubleshoot your process for you.

Comment: figured out the issue...i wasnt passing the parameters as argument list as my original code in the post.