# why is the directory being redirected to C:\?

Tags: powershell

I have the following script to remove folders/files remotely

```
$Directory = "E:\Data"
Invoke-Command -Computer $Server -ScriptBlock { 
    param ($dir, $name)

$f = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Where {$_.Name -Match "$name"}
If ($f) {
    $f | Foreach {
        Remove-Item $_ -confirm:$false -Recurse -Verbose 
    }
}
else {
    Write-Verbose "No file found"
}
} -ArgumentList $Directory, $DB
```

for some reason, it tries to look for files in `C:\users\documents` instead...even though i clearly defined the directory param at `E:\Data`

> Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Documents\file.3.db' because it does not
>   exist.

so `file.3.db` actually exists on `E:\Data`...yet somehow its merging that with `C:\` directory...which the file doesnt exist on and outputting that error message. i am confused how is that happening

EDIT:
the below code works just fine, but i updated it to that one above because i wanted file checking...though now that rendered the code to not work anymore:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $Server -ScriptBlock { 
    param ($dir, $name)
    Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | 
        Where {$_.Name -Match "$name"} | 
            Remove-Item -confirm:$false -Recurse -Verbose 
} -ArgumentList $Directory, $DB
```

Comment: it looks like the `$f` variable is not being filled. try removing the unneeded double quotes around `$name` in the `$f = ` line of code. ///// also, try listing out the two parameters as they are inside the scriptblock.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey check my update in te post. basically the second piece of code i have works just fine. but i wanted to update it to have file checking as well, which results in this new issue i have with the first code in my post

Comment: try as follows. `Remove-Item $_.FullName` or  `$f | Remove-Item`

Comment: @rokumaru Remove-Item $_.FullName did the trick!!!!

Comment: @Cataster - i see that rokumaru got the answer you needed. kool! glad to know that you have it working as needed ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug this all locally and see the issue.  Mainly, you need to Select the FullName with `-ExpandProperty` as well.

```
$Directory = "d:\temp"
Invoke-Command -Computer $Server -ScriptBlock { 
    param ($dir, $name)

    Write-Output "dir='$dir', name='$name'"

    $f = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Where {$_.Name -Match $name} | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
    if ($f) {
        $f | Foreach {
            Remove-Item $_ -confirm:$false -Verbose -WhatIf
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Verbose "No file found"
    }
} -ArgumentList $Directory, "test*"
```

NOTE: I added a `-WhatIf` to the Remove-Item call for testing so I did not remove any data in my machine.  I also removed `-Recurse` since that makes no sense to me...but you can add it back to my test code of course.

From this, I think you can get your final solution working.

Comment: the reason i am specifying recurse is because i have to manually confirm otherwise the following prompt:  There are 1 file(s) to delete...


Confirm
The item at E:\Data\file.3.db has children and the Recurse parameter was not
specified. If you continue, all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [?] Help (default is "Y"):

Comment: even though i am using -Confirm:$false, its somehow still prompting me to specify recurse